# What is the correct use of the OR function (|) within R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph two sets of data using ggplot and am having an issue attempting to use the OR function within this line of code.

```
statistics2 <- statistics2[startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name), prefix = "Health expenditure per capita"), ]
```

From my understanding this would be correct:

```
statistics2 <- statistics2[startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name), prefix = "Health expenditure per capita"|"Life expectancy at birth, total (years)"), ]
```

But returns the error:

```
Error in "Health expenditure per capita" | "Life expectancy at birth, total (years)" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Can somebody help me to understand what the issue is, from what I have read elsewhere my use of the OR (|) function is correct.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The expression on each side of `|` needs to be logical - so you can't use it to just separate options like you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prefix` argument in `startsWith(x, prefix)` is a character vector. When you write `prefix = "foo"`, that is a character vector of length one and equal to `prefix = c("foo")`.

The `prefix` vector is "recycled", until each element in `x` has been matched once. For a `prefix` vector of length one, the single element in `prefix` is matched against all elements of `x`:

```
startsWith(x = c("one", "two", "three"), prefix = "t")
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If prefix has more than one element, the elements of `prefix` are matched against the elements of `x` until all elements of `x` have been matched:

```
startsWith(x = c("one", "two", "three"), prefix = c("t", "o"))
# "one" "two" "three"
# "t"   "o"   "t"     <= prefix is repeated until end of x
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want to match each element of `x` against each element of `prefix`, you have to run `startsWith` for each element of prefix individually:

```
startsWith(x = c("one", "two", "three"), prefix = "t") | startsWith(x = c("one", "two", "three"), prefix = "o")
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So the solution to your problem is something like:

```
statistics2 <- statistics2[
    startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name), prefix = "Health expenditure per capita")
    |
    startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name), prefix = "Life expectancy at birth, total (years)"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prefix = "Health expenditure per capita" | prefix = "Life expectancy at birth, total (years)")
```

Add the 'prefix =' to the other side as well.

Comment: That does make more sense! Although I still get the error:
Error: unexpected '=' in "statistics2 <- statistics2[startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name), prefix = "Health expenditure per capita"| prefix ="

Answer (score 0):

`startsWith` allows you to use a vector for `prefix`, so the following will work

```
statistics2 <- statistics2[startsWith(as.character(statistics2$Series_Name),
      prefix = c("Health expenditure per capita","Life expectancy at birth total (years)")), ]
```